# How to encode a stream (filestream of a file (pdf, ppt etcc.) from s3 bucket) to base64string in python for sending across network using Rest API

Tags: python, c#, rest, encoding, boto3

How to encode a stream (filestream of a file (pdf, ppt etcc.) from s3 bucket using boto3) to base64string in python for sending across network

In essential how to do the base64 conversion below in python for c# sample below
**DocumentBody = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)**

```
private void UploadDocumentsToEntity(Entity entity, Byte[] bytes, string fileName, string documentDescription, SystemUser systemUser)
    {
        Annotation setupAnnotation = new Annotation()
        {
            Subject = documentDescription, //"Entity - Document Attachment" + fileName
            FileName = fileName,
            DocumentBody = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes),
            MimeType = GetMimeType(fileName),
            ObjectId = new EntityReference(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id),
            OwnerId = new EntityReference("systemuser", systemUser.Id)
        };

        Guid annotationId = _serviceProxy.Create(setupAnnotation);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

we simply do

```
base64_string = base64.b64encode(bytes).decode('utf-8')
```